# Which version of USB-C port does my laptop have?

Tags: usb, usb-3, usb-c, usb-3.1-type-c

I own Huawei Matebook X Pro and I am about to buy a docking station or port replicator to connect to laptop's USB-C port. Apparently, there are port replications for two main versions right now:

- USB-C 3.1/3.2 Gen 1, also called USB-C 3.0 (5Gbps)
- USB-C 3.1/3.2 Gen 2 (10Gbps).

How do I know which one my laptop supports? The [Huawei Spec on their website](https://consumer.huawei.com/en/laptops/matebook-x-pro-2020/specs/) say just:

> USB-C x 2 (support data, charging and DisplayPort)

Is there a way how can I figure out which version of USB-C I have? Perhaps directly on my computer? It has Windows 10 Pro.

EDIT: This is what my Device Manager says:

[image]

This is an output of UsbTreeView:

[image]

PS: Likewise, [I have trouble figuring out what version of USB-C connection does the port replicator support!](https://superuser.com/q/1648663/93604)

Comment: That it supports DisplayPort suggests it may be one of the higher modes as I'm sure "alt mode" (DisplayPort) was a 3.1 feature added later in the spec. Note though that if you use the DisplayPort mode then depending on how many USB lanes the graphics uses for the display it may drop the hub out of USB3 mode entirely and down to USB2. Depending on the hub, display, and your laptop USB you may be able to retain a slower USB3 mode along with display output. "It depends" and "you'll have to try it and find out" may be bet best answers you'll get.

Answer (score 1):

It's some version of USB 3. Hard to say which one based on the specs.

Avoid the USB-C 2.0 version, it would be *slooow*. Any of the other two will work. If your ports are gen 2, the gen 1 replicator will only replicate gen 1. If your ports are gen 1, then gen 2 replicator will still replicate only gen 1.

Comment: thank you. Isn't there any way to figure the version of my ports on my computer?

Comment: @InnateImunityisTheWay [UsbTreeView](https://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbtreeview_e.html) probably, but I've never tried this myself so I can't tell you what to look for, and the program isn't exactly user friendly.

Comment: Thanks, I have added output of UsbTreeView. Help is welcome :-)